# How can I root honeysuckle in water?

Tags: soil, propagation, water, honeysuckle

Okay so I've done this a couple times but it never seems to work. I've tried doing it just in water but it died of transplant shock and too little sun. Then I've tried outside in soil (topping soil I think) and I'm trying the slipping method at the moment. I will soon be moving so I need an almost guaranteed method to do this. I will buy what I need but what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

I take it your *Lonicera* is not growing in a pot (or you would just take it with you) so suggest upping your chances of success by trying three different approaches:

1. [Layering.](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=358) Might be slow.
2. Softwood cutting/s: Remove [from the parent plant with a heel, pulling off the stem with a ‘tail’ of bark from the previous season’s growth. The heel is then dipped in hormone rooting compound.](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=307)
3. Leaf bud cuttings (my preference). Details [here](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/chiwonlee/plsc368/student/papers03/pmurdock/propagationofhoneysucklevine.htm).

Personally I would have expected "in water" to work well, given a succulent young shoot (taken early in the day is advised) but presume you are not keen to try that again.

Answer (score 1):

To increase your chance of rooting with cuttings, try dipping the cuttings in rooting hormones. Alternative would be honey or aspirin.